# Getting data from python script which is receiving data continuously

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a transmitter that keeps on transmitting data and I have a receiver that keeps on receiving data.
When I transmit the data I note down the time, when I receive the data I note down its time. Scripts are running continuously. I am running these scripts in parallel. Now I want to get sending and receiving time in another script where I can do further processing.

**Transmitting Script**

```
import serial
import time
while 1:
    for i in range(4): 
        msg = str(i+1)
        msgstat = 'A' + msg

        tx_t = time.time()# 

        sertx.write(msg.encode())
        tx_t=str(tx_t)#I want this time
```

**Receiving Script**

```
import serial
import time

serrx = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)

while 1:

    read_serial=serrx.readline()
    rx_t = time.time()
    rx_t=str(rx_t)# Here I want to capture this time
```

I want those 2 above times in a single python script so that I can do further processing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few solutions.

You could use a messaging system for example, like redis.

In your scripts, post a message in redis PUBSUB, with the times, and have a script listen for both channels.

You could also use a single asynchronous script (or using threads) to both post and receive messages, and have the data you need in it...

Comment: I am transmitting and receiving at speed of light.
I am new to this can you please elaborate or give some useful resources where I can read about these things
Thanks

Comment: @Ambuje Gupta https://github.com/ryananguiano/python-redis-timeseries

Comment: @AmbujeGupta You can sample the data at some frequency in such a status that it does make sense. Otherwise, the data might be too much. It sounds interesting.